# How can I avoid mysqli connection and how do I use real_escape_string?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

Here an excerpt from php class:

***DB.class.php***

```
class DB {    
    protected $db_name = '';
    protected $db_user = '';
    protected $db_pass = '';
    protected $db_host = '';
    protected $connection;

    public function connect() {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
        mysqli_select_db($this->connection, $this->db_name);

        return true;
    }

    public function processRowSet($rowSet, $singleRow = false) {
        $resultArray = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rowSet)) {
            array_push($resultArray, $row);
        }

        if ($singleRow === true)
            return $resultArray[0];

        return $resultArray;
    }

    public function insert($data, $table) {
        $columns = "";
        $values = "";

        foreach ($data as $column => $value) {
            $columns .= ($columns == "") ? "" : ", ";
            $columns .= $column;
            $values .= ($values == "") ? "" : ", ";
            $values .= $value;
        }

        $sql = "insert into $table ($columns) values ($values)";

        mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($this->connection));

        //return the ID of the user in the database.
        return mysqli_insert_id($this->connection);
    }
}
```

***insert-entry.php***

```
require_once 'db.php';

$headline = $_POST['headline'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

$data = array(
        'headline' => $headline,
        'description' => $description
    );

$db->insert($data, 'entries');´
```

I have three questions on the professional use of this class:

- **Avoding mysqli connection:** The class was mysql before and I changed it to mysqli. Is there any way to avoid that I always need to pass the mysql connection as a parameter when I want to do mysqli operations, such as mysqli_query()?
- **Sanitizing user input:** How can I build in $db->real_escape_string? I want it to be applied for all values that come from the user and go into my database. Is it something I can add in the insert function in DB.class.php or do I have to apply this in my outer php files, for example insert-entry.php in this example?
- **Catching an error:** In an outer php file such as insert-entry.php in this example, how
  can I catch an error of a function such as the $db->insert() function? My goal is that
  if an error occurs the user is directed to an error page (via
  header:location). Important: I want to be able to create individual error handlings in different php files.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: Use the OOP aproach instead of the procedural one

Comment: You mostly don't need `real_escape_string` - use parameterisation instead. Your insert is vulnerable to SQL injection presently.

Comment: I would recommend using PDO and bind your variables.

Comment: The easy answer: use an MVC framework, the work is already done for you.